# Proper generation of javadocs links to external libraries

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have developed a Java library that makes use of some other libraries also developed by me. All of them published online and managed with Maven.

My problem concerns proper inclusion of links in the generated Javadocs. 
For example, if a class in my library extends various interfaces, links to those classes appear only for the interfaces that are part of my project.

Then, my question is: how can I instruct maven to generate the javadocs so the link to classes outside my project (available online) are properly resolved ?

Comment: Does this help? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/links-configuration.html

Comment: Hi @Devon_C_Miller, just updated the question with that info

Comment: I believe Maven tries to resolve the links, so the URLs need to be fetchable when Maven runs.  If they are not available as a URL, try http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#offlineLinks and see if that works.

Comment: the url links are fetchable, e.g., these are two I am ussing: http://jgum.github.io/javadocs/ or http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/. Maybe I need to run mvn with a special flag ?